# iText Java library

Tags: itext

**I need to download data from my grid into PDf using iText Java Library. Anyone please let me know how to do that . Also it should have page numbers in that.**

We may have charts also in it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go through the book [iText in Action](http://itextpdf.com/book/toc.php) and this [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=118) will help you to solve your page number problem.